# Play Framework 2 multiple production instances

Tags: playframework, production-environment, multiple-instances, playframework-2.1

I have created two separate Play! framework 2.1.0 applications: a `front-end` and a `cms`, which is supposed to be running on a different ports. The projects share a lot of code, and connect to the same database (with the same credentials).

I've packaged the two projects with `play dist`. I can start either one fine (`front-end/start -Dhttp.port=1234 &`), which creates a PID file and runs as expected.

However, as soon as I fire up the other project (`back-end/start -Dhttp.port=5678 &`), I see that project starting, but the first project gets killed!

Both projects work fine when independant of each other, and the order in which I start them seems to make no difference.

I have changed the `application secret` so that they are different.

Note that the first process gets killed when trying to access it in the browser (after verifying that the second one was working), but it's PID file never gets deleted.

Edit: 
As suggested below, I ran both apps in two terminals, this is what happened:

```
./start -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dlogger.root=DEBUG -Dlogger.play=DEBUG -Dlogger.application=DEBUG
Play server process ID is 12870
[debug] c.j.b.BoneCPDataSource - JDBC URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/hp?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci, Username = hp, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partition) = 5, helper threads = 0, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/hp?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
[debug] o.r.Reflections - going to scan these urls:
jar:file:/var/play-apps/hp-frontend-1.0/lib/hp-frontend_2.10-1.0.jar!/
jar:file:/var/play-apps/hp-frontend-1.0/lib/play.play_2.10-2.1.0.jar!/

[info] o.r.Reflections - Reflections took 213 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 12 keys and 24 values 
[info] c.a.e.s.c.DefaultServerFactory - DatabasePlatform name:default platform:mysql
[debug] c.a.e.c.AbstractNamingConvention - Using maxConstraintNameLength of 64
[debug] c.a.e.s.l.t.ThreadPool - ThreadPool grow created [Ebean-default.0] size[0]
[debug] c.a.e.a.ClassLoadContext - Context and Caller ClassLoader's same instance of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
[info] c.a.e.s.s.SubClassManager - SubClassFactory parent ClassLoader       [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader]
[debug] c.a.e.a.ClassLoadContext - Context and Caller ClassLoader's same instance of sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
[debug] c.a.e.s.t.DefaultTypeManager - Registering Joda data types
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - BeanPersistControllers[0] BeanFinders[0] BeanPersistListeners[0] BeanQueryAdapters[0]
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Skipping transient field _ebean_identity in play.db.ebean.Model
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Skipping transient field _ebean_identity in play.db.ebean.Model
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Skipping transient field _ebean_identity in play.db.ebean.Model
[info] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Explicit sequence on models.CmsPage but not supported by DB Platform - ignored
[info] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Explicit sequence on models.Image but not supported by DB Platform - ignored
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptor - BeanDescriptor initialise models.CmsPage
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptor - BeanDescriptor initialise models.Image
[debug] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptor - BeanDescriptor initialise models.PagesImages
[info] c.a.e.s.d.BeanDescriptorManager - Entities enhanced[3] subclassed[0]
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - ObjectName = JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - name = JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - Send create notification of object JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - JMX.mbean.registered JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - ObjectName = Ebean:server=default2,function=Logging
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - name = Ebean:server=default2,function=Logging
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - Send create notification of object Ebean:function=Logging,server=default2
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - JMX.mbean.registered Ebean:server=default2,function=Logging
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - ObjectName = Ebean:server=default2,key=AutoFetch
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - name = Ebean:server=default2,key=AutoFetch
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - Send create notification of object  Ebean:key=AutoFetch,server=default2
[debug] j.m.mbeanserver - JMX.mbean.registered Ebean:server=default2,key=AutoFetch
[debug] c.a.ebean.Ebean - GlobalProperties.isSkipPrimaryServer()
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationFactory - Configuring ehcache from ehcache.xml found in the classpath: jar:file:/var/play-apps/hp-frontend-1.0/lib/play.play_2.10-2.1.0.jar!/ehcache.xml
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationFactory - Configuring ehcache from URL: jar:file:/var/play-apps/hp-frontend-1.0/lib/play.play_2.10-2.1.0.jar!/ehcache.xml
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationFactory - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
[debug] n.s.e.c.BeanHandler - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
[debug] n.s.e.c.BeanHandler - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
[debug] n.s.e.CacheManager - Creating new CacheManager with default config
[debug] n.s.e.u.PropertyUtil - propertiesString is null.
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class  specified. Skipping...
[debug] n.s.e.Cache - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
[debug] n.s.e.Cache - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationHelper - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified.  Skipping...
[debug] n.s.e.s.MemoryStore - Initialized net.sf.ehcache.store.NotifyingMemoryStore for play
[debug] n.s.e.Cache - Initialised cache: play
[debug] n.s.e.c.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'play'.
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
---> Browsed to :9000 here. Waited a minute, then this appeared:
Killed
```

And the second process:

```
 ./start -Dhttp.port=9010 -Dlogger.play=DEBUG
Play server process ID is 12758
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/hp?    useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9010
->Here, I browsed to :9010 and after 30 secs it started working
^C
```

(The debug output was exactly the same, so ommitted it here)

I tried the process multiple times, with some minor variations in the results: when waiting for the 1st app to reach 'listening for HTTP' before firing up the 2nd, the 2nd never got past 'database [default] connected'.

Comment: I created two play projects and started them after each other, but I can't reproduce your error. What is in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is weird, you should be able to fire up both apps in one time and there should be no problem. Running different app's on different ports (or even running **the same** app in many instances) is quite common scenario and I can't even imagine what causes the described behavior.

Fact that `RUNNING_PID` file remains undeleted indicates, that there is some abnormal program termination occuring, so probably some of your elements aren't allowed to share some resources with other virtual machine(s).

Most probably it could be found in the logs and or terminal. Start your application without `&` character - so it will keep the log directly in the terminal - check what it says after first app is killed.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and added the response to my question